# How to change the colour of the Switch thumb in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, uiswitch, toggleswitch

I have this `Switch` in my app, on iPhone it is displaying correctly, with a white thumb regardless of whether the switch is on or off. However, on web, when the switch is on, it is this blue colour, that is defined nowhere in my app. I cannot figure out how to override it.

```
<Switch
       trackColor={{ false: colours.darkGrey, true: colours.primary }}
       ios_backgroundColor={colours.darkGrey}
       thumbColor={colours.white}
       onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
       value={notificationEnabled}
       style={styles.switch}
/>
```

The switch `switch` style:

```
switch: {
    transform: [{ scaleX: 0.7 }, { scaleY: 0.7 }],
  },
```

I am not too bothered that the shapes are not the same, but the colours should match.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try ```thumbColor="white"```, it looks like your ```colours.white``` is not white ... if not working then you use super old React Native version, cuz this was issue back in rn 50 versions, its working tested on RN 0.67 works PERFECT, also tested on Expo 44 ...

Comment: If you add the color value directly: `thumbColor={'white'}` does it work? In my case it works.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the `Switch` component when used via React Native Web has different props that aren't defined in the types.

To fix your specific issue you will also need to provide the prop `activeThumbColor={colours.white}`

For more info, see: https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/switch/